# In sql To use ALL command instead of MAX command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Find `sids` with the highest rating with all command.

I Find it with `max` command by writing

```
select S.sid,S.sname 
from Sailors S 
where S.rating = (select max(S1.rating) from Sailors S1)
```

But also I want to find it by using `all` command so I write it by writing

```
select S.sid,S.sname 
from Sailors S 
where  S.rating > all (select S.rating from Sailors S)
```

But it Doesn't give the same result.

What is My error? How can I regulate it?

Comment: Have you tried using `S.rating >= all ...` instead?

Comment: Thank you  Chris.İt is solved by your answer.Also thank you too Mahmoud for your answer

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL-Server, you can also simply use `ORDER BY` combined with `TOP (1)` and **[`WITH TIES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)** specification:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
    S.sid, S.sname 
FROM Sailors S 
ORDER BY S.rating DESC ;
```

Answer (score 6):

You simply need to modify your query to the following:

```
select S.sid,S.sname 
from Sailors S 
where  S.rating >= all (select S.rating from Sailors S)
```

While Mahmoud is correct in part about what is wrong with your condition currently, adding the possibility of equality gives you identical behavior to the `MAX` query, since each element in the set must be greater or equal to itself. (Mahmoud's point that no element can be greater than itself is accurate.)

See [this SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23a1b/4) that Mahmoud kindly provided.

As ypercube points out in the comments, this method does not work if any values in the column are NULL. It should still work fine if you modify the subquery to specify `WHERE rating IS NOT NULL`, or for `NOT NULL` columns.

Comment: +1 - Sorry, You are absolutely right. I don't know how I thought of this this way. Thanks. Here is a SQL Fiddle Demo, If you wish to use it in your answer: [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23a1b/4).

Comment: It sounds like Gokhan already has his solution, but I'll add that to the answer for future askers. Thanks.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. Please add that it will **not** work as expected if there is any `NULL` in the `rating` column in the table.